# Type mismatch, can' t convert from element Object to String

Tags: java, string, object, mismatch

I copied this code LITERALLY from this website: https://www.w3schools.com/java/showjava.asp?filename=demo_hashmap_loop_key

But it still gives an error as mentioned above referring to: 'for (String i : capitalCities.keySet())!'

Somebody knows how to correct this mistake??

```java
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap capitalCities = new HashMap();
    capitalCities.put("England", "London");
    capitalCities.put("Germany", "Berlin");
    capitalCities.put("Norway", "Oslo");
    capitalCities.put("USA", "Washington DC");

    for (String i : capitalCities.keySet()) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `HashMap<String, String> capitalCities = new HashMap<>();`.

Comment: That's right Mr. Slaw Thanks!! Amazing that such a mistake is made on a Java tutorial site, isn't it?

Comment: I think it's a rendering issue. If you look at the page source you'll see it uses the parameterized types, it just isn't showing the `<...>` likely due to some issue with the HTML being used. Also, check out [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/) if you want to know a little more about parameterized types versus raw types.

Comment: It's a rendering issue. view-source:https://www.w3schools.com/java/showjava.asp?filename=demo_hashmap_loop_key in Firefox shows that the actual line is `HashMap<String, String> capitalCities = new HashMap<String, String>();`.

Answer (score 2):

Your program will throw the below compilation error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String
```

From your code, `capitalCities.keySet()` will return Set of generic type. So, in order to return the String Set, either we can use one of the below solution.

Solution 1: `for (Object i : capitalCities.keySet())` Changing the data type of 'i' as generic Object.

Solution 2: `HashMap<String, String> capitalCities = new HashMap<String, String>();` We can define datatype for the key and the value of the map as String.

Note: For code readability, it is recommended to use "Solution 2".

Comment: Note that `keySet()` returns a `Set<K>` (or a `Set` when using raw types), not an array.